# Get error messages when $wpdb->insert() returns false?

Tags: database, wpdb, errors

`$wpdb->insert()` returns `false` which I've learned means that the insert failed. Now, I would like to know why it fails with the insert.

According to this ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32315 the problem could be that the value is either too long or contains bad characters.

Here is the insert query:

```
$result = $wpdb->insert('table', $ins_args, array('%d', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'));
```

It's difficult to show the `$ins_args` array values since some values are pretty long. Specially the one for field named `value`. But I use type `longtext` for that field. And this insert is used a lot. And most times it works with success. So it really feels like a encoding or size problem.

How do I get to know what the problem is? `$wpdb->last_error` is empty

Comment: Check $wpdb->last_error for inserting error

Comment: @Anton Lukin Yea sorry should have told that. Have of course tried that but it's just empty.

Comment: Try to debug it. Use $wpdb->last_query after inserting, then make this query via mysql client to see the error. Is it possible?

Comment: @Anton Lukin Even though the last query is an `insert()`, the `$wpdb->last_query` right after shows an `SELECT * FROM ....`-query.

Comment: We can win it :) add savequeries in your wp-config.php https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110270/126253

Comment: @Anton Lukin Damn it I got wring about the return. It returns `false`, not `0`. It's a bit difficult to get the queries in the footer since my operations is done with ajax. But I tried to place it after an the code in the php that ajax calls. And then called it from the browser. Now I found that something is breaking on the way, in the loop. Have to break down what that is about. But it's something later after the failing insert. So there's still a problem there. But hard to debug.. I'll keep trying...

Comment: @Anton Lukin Okay I now found the query. So, apparently this fails: `[75] => Array (  [0] => INSERT INTO results (parent_id, parent_id, key_code, value, url, cat_ids) VALUES (0, 7, 'posts', '', '', '')  [1] => 0.0037600994110107 [2] => do_action('wp_ajax_my_save_result'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, my_save_result, pw_save, PW->save_result, PW->get_posts )`

Comment: is it ok double parent_id, parent_id in your query?

Comment: @Anton Lukin Sorry that's wrong, the second is `parent_x_id`. Wanna make it a bit secret.

Comment: Okay I succeeded to fix it by sanitize the `url` and `value` with `esc_url()` and `esc_html()` before the `insert();`. Still bad with no error messages about it...

Answer (score 17):

`$wpdb->insert()` method returns `false` if the row could not be inserted. Otherwise, it returns the number of affected rows (which will always be 1).

You can turn error echoing on and off with the `show_errors` and `hide_errors`, respectively.

```
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?> 
<?php $wpdb->hide_errors(); ?>
```

You can also print the error (if any) generated by the most recent query with `print_error`.

```
<?php $wpdb->print_error(); ?>
```

You can also use `$last_error` field, which will contain the most recent error text generated by MySQL.

Comment: Would be good to see an example of the `$last_error` field. Is it just `$wpdb->last_error`?

Comment: Yes, exactly `$wpdb->last_error`

Comment: Note that, if a write is aborted because a column is too long, no error is returned.  That is, $wpdb->last_error` will be empty, and neither `$wpdb->show_errors()` and  `$wpdb->hide_errors()` will help. See my answer below for a way to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, `wp-db.php` returns false with no error, if the data you are trying to write to a column is too long to fit.  This becomes a nightmare to debug without explicitly checking each column's length (and it's hard to know the lengths, though wp-db.php does provide internal functions).

I've created a tiny drop-in override which modifies wpdb behaviour to return an error in this scenario.  To install it, you simply copy and paste it into your WordPress wp-content/db.php file.  It overrides only a single, short, wpdb method (`process_fields()`) to add an error message identifying the column that is too long.  Note that db.php will survive core upgrades, and you can simply remove the wp-content/db.php file at any time to revert to pure core wpdb.

Although I use this myself, as usual, test before use and usage is at your own peril.

The error code is originally taken from an [idea by Liam Murphy here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/331206/18358).

[Gist for drop in db.php here](https://gist.github.com/briancoogan/054cf3afcfb761d59e06020251bcd35c)

Comment: Finally fixed in WordPress v5.9. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32315#comment:82

Comment: Finally!! Thanks.